# Any idea why my code keeps producing syntax error?

Tags: php, html, sql, syntax-error

I can't seem to find where either a semi colon or a "}" is needed

```
for ($period=1; $period<6; $period++)
  {
     echo "<tr><td>".$period."</td>";  
     for ($room=0; $room<sizeof($rooms_array); $room++)
       {
         $sql = "SELECT Username FROM Booking WHERE RoomID ='".$rooms_array[$room]."' AND Period = '".$period."' AND Date = '".$sentdate."'";
         $result= sqlite_query($con,$sql);
         $row = sqlite_fetch_array($result);
         if($row['Username']==$_SESSION['Username'])
           {
             echo "<td>Booked By ".$row['Username']."</td>"
           }
       }
   }    

?>
```

Comment: What syntax error do you get?

Comment: if you format your code you might find it easier to visually detect when things are missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a semicolon after your echo statement:

```
{echo "<td>Booked By ".$row['Username']."</td>";}
```

Errors like this might be easier to find if you adopted a clearer block/indent style. Your code is pretty hard to read.

For example:

```
for ($period=1; $period<6; $period++)
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$period."</td>";  
    for ($room=0; $room<sizeof($rooms_array); $room++)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT Username FROM Booking WHERE RoomID ='".$rooms_array[$room]."' AND Period = '".$period."' AND Date = '".$sentdate."'";
        $result= sqlite_query($con,$sql);
        $row = sqlite_fetch_array($result);
        if($row['Username']==$_SESSION['Username'])
        {
            echo "<td>Booked By ".$row['Username']."</td>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing `;` here:

```
{echo "<td>Booked By ".$row['Username']."</td>"}
                                              ^
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo "<td>Booked By ".$row['Username']."</td>"` is missing a semicolon